# How does VRF add random numbers to a contract storage variables without calling a transaction on that contract?

Tags: storage, chainlink, vrf

After calling `Request Random Words` on a VRF consumer, I can see that the request was fulfilled in the contract and the storage now contains the random numbers. However, I don't see any transactions on the VRF consumer contract that fulfilled this request. I thought to edit storage variables on a contract you had to send that contract a transactions. What's going on here, some sort of `delegatecall` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VRF Consumer contract calls its `fulfillRandomWords` function, [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x271682DEB8C4E0901D1a1550aD2e64D568E69909#code#F22#L556) it is on Ethereum Mainnet.

To see those transactions on Etherscan, navigate to the "Internal Txns" tab.